# Distance to set defined as subzero level set of a continuous function

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

I am searching for strategies on how to prove/disprove that scalar functions "capture" the distance to the subzero level set of the same function. (Or what topics to study to become better at these kind of problems.)

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous scalar function, and let $S$ be$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(x) \leq 0 \}$. Let $d(x,S)$ be the distance from the point $x$ to the set $S$, i.e. $d(x,S):=\inf_{s \in S} |x-s|$.

How do you check if $f$ satisfies the bounds $$\alpha(d(x,S)) \leq f(x) \leq \beta(d(x,S)), \quad \forall x \notin S,$$ where $\alpha, \beta:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ are continuous strictly increasing functions with $\alpha(0)=\beta(0)=0$?

If $S$ is not compact, this property may not hold. E.g. $f(x) = x_1/(x_2^2+1)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$  defines the set $S=\{x : x_1 \leq 0\}$, but $f$ cannot be lower bounded by any function $\alpha(d(x,S))$. This is easy to see, but I am unable to formulate why this function has this result. The gradient of $f$ vanishes as $x_2 \to \infty$, but vanishing gradient is by itself not enough. To see this, note that $f(x)=x_1^3$ defines the same set $S$, has vanishing gradient at the boundary of $S$, that is at $\{x : x_1=0\}$, and satisfies said bounds with $d(x,S)^3 \leq f(x) \leq d(x,S)^3, \quad \forall x \notin S.$

A seemingly trivial example for which I want to show this "bounded by distance to the subzero level set property" is $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)= 1-x^\top x - x^\top y$, where the set is $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) \leq 0\}$.

Comment: Thank you! Your correction for the last formula was incorrect. I have corrected it now. So it may also be written f(t,u,v,w) = 1-t^2-u^2-t*v-u*w.